# Disbarment or lesser discipline, United States

Tags: criminal-law

I had a bitter criminal legal struggle with a prosecutor that consistently showed no interest in knowing the truth (me meeting with him initially before I had any public defender), taking things fully out of context if possible, not standing by the plea bargain offer I later accepted, and numerous other very difficult treatment for me. As far as I can tell, he is prejudiced against me based on his on-going actions (which my now hired private attorney agrees).

It turns out, before I had private attorney, a woman working with and for one of the public defenders, took my increasing complaints that I emailed first to the court of it's wrongs (fairly numerous) and then to her later as a copy, and gave it to the prosecutor, who then literally desperately used it to try to do me more harm.  My attorney told him he needs to immediately cease from reading these emails and place them in an envelope (and I believe return them to the public defender), because he was breaking attorney client privilege, and the prosecutor simply kept on and disregarded him. He then sought to inflict more punishment onto me using another angle if possible.

My attorney has "socialized" notifying the "disbarment agency" with him, however I want to know my rights in this matter. I don't particularly want this man/prosecutor harm, however there has been a gross miscarriage of justice in my case.  Are there levels of discipline?   I'd really like to just sit down with this prosecutor and get him to understand that he's really been endlessly attacking the wrong person in this situation.  How does disbarment work overall?  Are there "hand slaps" or various levels of discipline?

Comment: When you say "me meeting with him initially before I had any public defender", who initiated the meeting, and had you requested a public defender (or lawyer in general) before this point?

Comment: Also, what is your jurisdiction?

Comment: I sought to meet with him, and did not have a public defender at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different levels of discipline. When it comes to formal discipline, the lowest is probably an admonishment, and there can be a range of other penalties -- including monetary sanctions, continuing education requirements, and temporary suspensions -- before reaching the point of disbarment. Total disbarment is a very serious sanction and rarely used in most jurisdictions.

The [Arizona State Bar](https://www.azbar.org/lawyerconcerns/disciplineprocess/#Discipline%20Imposed) has more information on the process and on the particular sanctions available in that state:

> **What discipline can be imposed?**
>
> If the charge against a lawyer is found to violate the Rules of Professional Conduct, the lawyer may be required to pay restitution, ordered to pay costs, be issued an admonition, be placed on probation, reprimanded, suspended, or disbarred.